# How to store json string in mysql using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I want to store my JSON string into database but when i give json string it is not working but when i give simple value it work

this is what i am doing

```
// $data contain json string 
// info is a TEXT type in mysql
$q = "Update user set info = $data where userid = $id";
$sql= $this->db->query($q);
```

Comment: you got missing quotes

Comment: You need to put $data in quotes `'$data'`

Comment: \*cough* Use prepared statements \*cough*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really check your error log or enable display_errors to see where the query is failing, but my guess is you probably just need to wrap the data field in quotes. Try this:

```
// $data contain json string 
// info is a TEXT type in mysql
$q = "Update user set info = '$data' where userid = $id";
$sql= $this->db->query($q)
```

Comment: you might also want to escape the data string if your class doesn't already do so. (mysql_real_escape_string)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the quotes around $data and $id. And you need to close the string before concatenating variables, like this:

```
$q = "Update user set info = '". $data."' where userid = '". $id."'";
$sql= $this->db->query($q);
```